# How to "bind" a character to a vi command?

Tags: vi

Sometimes, I am writing primarily in English and I need to enter a special unicode character, like the degree symbol or the Greek letter theta. However, the two option of either memorizing the Unicode hex value, or copy/pasting it from the Internet are both very unsatisfactory.

Is there a way I can create a custom command (say :theta) such that when I enter the command, it automatically inserts the special character exactly where I need it?

Comment: Even though I don't think this question is something that shouldn't be on stackoverflow, you might get a better answer here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Lookup `:abbr` and `:map` for starters.  I use `:map` quite often for sequences of `vim` commands, but more typically use yank and pull to deal with awkward characters.  You might use `"tyl` to yank a letter (such as θ) into a named buffer (`t` in this case) and then pull it when needed (from command mode) with `"tp`.  You can build up a repertoire if you're careful.